# PDF generation in PHP 4.3.2 :(

Tags: php, pdf, pdf-generation

I'm faced with having to generate some fairly basic PDFs on a server which is running php 4.3.2 unfortunately.

So that pretty much renders most things impossible such as google's domPDF etc.. PDFlib is *not* compiled in so I can't use any of that either.

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: **WHY** are you running php 4.3.2?

Comment: I am not running it. My clients client is, they insisted they wouldn't change.

Comment: I've marked this as answered now and I've since convinced my client to wait until the site is hosted on a new server in a few weeks that I'm fortunately in control of so it's running php5 etc.. phewph.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using an older version of fpdf and HTML2PDF (from the link below.) It's certainly not ideal, but then neither is a 7 year old version of php.

http://www.macronimous.com/resources/Converting_HTML2PDF_using_PHP.asp

Answer (score 2):

use this [R&OS PDF Class](http://www.ros.co.nz/pdf/) to achieve this task.. This is fairly simple and light weight class and requires no module etc to be installed on the server.

Answer (score 2):

You could try out DocRaptor.com, which is a webservice that will let you convert [html to pdf](http://docraptor.com).

Comment: Almost forgot - there's a php library here: https://github.com/krewenki/php-docraptor

Answer (score 0):

You didn't mention if you were generating these from scratch or from existing PDF data. pdftk is a handy PDF manipulation library. You can shell out to it from PHP.